# BASh - while read within while read giving weird output

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop

I have the following beginning to a bash script;

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting ..."

while IFS="" read -r day || [ -n "$day" ]; do

    while IFS="" read -r meal || [ -n "$meal" ]; do

        echo "Please select a recipe for $meal on $day"

    done < lists/meals

done < lists/days
```

However, the output is this;

```
$ ./create.sh
 on mondayect a recipe for breakfast
 on mondayect a recipe for lunch
 on mondayect a recipe for dinner
Please select a recipe for snack on monday
 on tuesdayct a recipe for breakfast
 on tuesdayct a recipe for lunch
 on tuesdayct a recipe for dinner
Please select a recipe for snack on tuesday
 on wednesday a recipe for breakfast
```

etc...

I was expecting it to read;

```
$ ./create.sh
Please select a recipe for breakfast on monday
Please select a recipe for lunch on monday
Please select a recipe for dinner on monday
Please select a recipe for snack on monday
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Thank you.

Comment: Check you input files for windows line endings. If there is a `\r` in there, then the cursor jumps to the start of the line and text will be overwritten. For a quick check, use `< <(tr -d \\r file)` instead of `< file`.

Comment: `while IFS=$'\r' read ...` will also trim carriage returns from the end of lines as they're read.

Comment: I resolved this issue using your answers; as I was writing my bash script in Visual Studio Code on Windows, it was auto generating CRLF line endings in my text files.
I have now amended them to be LF instead and all works OK.